# SQL - Counting Wins and Losses

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a mySQL query for counting wins and losses from a table that contains each individual game result. The table looks like:

```
Season | winning_team | losing_team | winning_points | losing_points
 2003        1101          1102             65              45 
 2003        1104          1101             72              70
 2004        1102          1103             88              63
```

And I'd like to get something that looks like:

```
Season | team | wins | losses
 2003    1101    22      4
 2004    1101    12      16
 2003    1102    14      14
```

I really have no idea how to proceed. I can get query results that have just wins or just losses, but I can't seem to do both. This first query gets the number of wins:

```
SELECT Season, winning_team, COUNT(winning_points) as wins
FROM cbb.regular_season
GROUP BY Season, winning_team
```

Returning (example):

```
Season | winning_team | wins
 2003        1101        22      
 2004        1101        12      
 2003        1102        14
```

And this second gets losses:

```
SELECT Season, losing_team, COUNT(losing_points) as losses
FROM cbb.regular_season
GROUP BY Season, losing_team
```

Returning (example):

```
Season | losing_team | losses
 2003        1101        3      
 2004        1101        16      
 2003        1102        14
```

I'd like to group it all together so I can get the season, the team, and the number of wins and losses for every season for every team.

Comment: Any explanation on the result?

Comment: He perhaps want to count wins and losses for every year for every team

Comment: but still wont explain losses 4 for 1101?

Comment: Show us the table structure and what you tried so far. And a data sample.

Comment: The first table is just a sample, the second is a sample of what I would like the results of the query to look like. I'll edit in something I've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    season, team,
    count(case when outcome = 'W' then 1 else null end) as wins,
    count(case when outcome = 'L' then 1 else null end) as losses
from
    (
    select season, winning_team as team, 'W' as outcome from cbb.regular_season union all
    select season, losing_team as team, 'L' as outcome from cbb.regular_season
    ) as games
group by season, team
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the intermediate steps right. Now you need to get them together like this:

```
SELECT wins.Season
, wins.team
, wins.wins
, loses.loses
FROM (
    SELECT Season
    , winning_team as team
    , COUNT(1) as wins
    FROM cbb.regular_season
    GROUP BY Season, winning_team
) as wins
, (
    SELECT Season
    , losing_team
    , COUNT(1) as losses
    FROM cbb.regular_season
    GROUP BY Season, losing_team 
) as loses
WHERE wins.Season = loses.Season
AND wins.team = loses.team
```

I haven't tried it but it should work

#### edit

As mentioned in comment, this won't work if a team have only loses or only wins.

Comment: In a winless or lossless season there won't be a row for that team on one side of the inner join. The query will fail in that case.

Comment: My guess is there is still a record for each since there is a tie. They are still recorded.

Comment: I'm not talking about ties. I'm talking about a full season where the team either never wins or never loses.

Comment: That could be fixed with a full outer join but mysql doesn't support it, right?

Comment: I apologize if my earlier comment came off abrupt.

Comment: Don't worry :), it was a valid comment